# Run supervisor outside docker whereas nimbus runs as a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, apache-storm

I'm trying to run nimbus as container in docker and trying to use my machine as supervisor. I've tried the following. I've a docker compose that sets up nimbus and zookeeper containers

```
  nimbus:
    image: storm:2.4.0
    platform: linux/x86_64
    container_name: nimbus
    command: storm nimbus
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    links:
      - zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '6627:6627'

    networks:
      - storm

  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:3.6.2
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - '2181'
    volumes:
      - ~/data/zookeeper:/bitnami/zookeeper
    environment:
      - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
    networks:
      - storm

  ui:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: storm:2.4.0
    container_name: ui
    command: storm ui
    links:
      - nimbus
      - zookeeper
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"

    networks:
      - storm
```

I've exposed the two with ports. When I try to run `storm supervisor` from terminal, with `localhost` as nimbus seed and zookeeper server in `storm.yaml`, I get the following log and am not able to start the supervisor.

```
2022-11-03 19:15:55.866 o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn main-SendThread(localhost:2181) [INFO] Socket error occurred: localhost/127.0.0.1:2181: Connection refused
2022-11-03 19:15:55.971 o.a.s.d.s.Supervisor main [ERROR] supervisor can't create stormClusterState
2022-11-03 19:15:55.975 o.a.s.u.Utils main [ERROR] Received error in thread main.. terminating server...
java.lang.Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /storm
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.handleUncaughtException(Utils.java:663) ~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.handleUncaughtException(Utils.java:667) ~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.lambda$createDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler$2(Utils.java:1047) ~[storm-client-2.3.0.jar:2.3.0]
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1055) [?:?]
    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1050) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.dispatchUncaughtException(Thread.java:1997) [?:?]
```

I'm able to access the ui as localhost:9090. Can someone please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure that zookeeper is atually up and running? And why does the error-log tells you about version `2.3.0.`, while your docker configuration says `2.4.0.`?

Comment: @moosehead42 zookeeper is up, I think the storm I use in machine is 2.3 and the one in docker is 2.4, would that be the problem ? Will degrade and check once

Comment: Not entirely sure if this could be the error cause. Have you also checked your Zookeeper and Supervisor logs? I am not fully into docker, but are you sure that the zk-Port is also accessible for other clients?

Comment: @moosehead42 I'm able to run everything from within a single network in docker. Also able to ping them externally, but unable to make my machine a supervisor

Comment: Hard to tell whats the issue. Can you post also your `storm.yaml`? Have you tried on two different machines?